# Query works in SSMS but not from the C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

It's a basic car rent application, but I simplified it. Think that, there is only two variables in the table:

```
rentID: int   
carID: int
```

When I do THIS at SQL Server, this works:

```
UPDATE tblCars SET rentID=15 where carID=4
```

And this is the C# version. This line totally works with some basic commands. But since this has a lot of " and ' it doesn't work somehow? What am I doing wrong here?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblCars SET rentID= '" + Convert.ToInt32(rentID) +"'where carID='" + Convert.ToInt32(carID) + "'", con);
```

Comment: For a start you *should* use parameters from C#. You don't need to single quote numbers. You look like you need a space before `where`. If you insist on building a string like this, stop there in your debugger and copy the string out to SSMS, you'll soon see whats wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't tack things onto a question later, but for the 2nd you want `IS NULL`.

Comment: Sorry I can't ask any more questions that's why.

Comment: @DaleK: Too advanced. This is clearly a beginner who struggles with C# basics like string concatenation. With parameters one runs into various issues that need already some experience (strings are cropped silently to the parameter length which is often unwanted, in some constellations random incorrect behavior occurs if `Prepare()` is not called, if `Prepare()` is used one needs to know that `Parameters.AddWithValue(..)` does not work anymore etc.

Comment: Yes, this "'"" things are horrible, a nightmare. Who invented this?

Comment: @Christoph with respect I **completely** disagree. Not only should answers on this site never be dumbed down, the should **always** be the current best practice solution to the problem. But IMO id a developer can't get their head around parameters, they shouldn't be writing database access code.

Comment: @DaleK: There are lot of reasons _not_ to use parameters as well. Parameters are not the only valid best practice option. It's just the most commonly preached one. You don't get any more security in this example (SQL injection is not possible with Int32 values), the loss of speed through recompiling the query each time is negligible (and with option "Forced Parameterization" they are fully cached as well) but the increased debugging costs are not. When the query is a string one can simply paste it into SSMS and try it out or read it from the SQL profiler, with parametrized queries not as easy.

Comment: @Christoph you say a lot of reasons, but only mention easier debugging :) I've used both methods extensively and cannot think of a good reason to use string concat - not even debugging. Also I see far more questions on this site similar to this one then I do about people having issues with parameters. In fact I can't recall seeing a question involving a parameter issue at all. But there are string concat issues every day.

Comment: @DaleK: You managed to confuse me - I had to check. I really found 1 answer which I forgot to give credits, but all others got an upvote for each helpful answer.

Comment: @DaleK: Easier debugging and the reasons above: No unwanted cropping of string arguments, no incorrect behavior if `Prepare()` is not called (I haven't found out why or in which constellation), no seemingly available interfaces that one finds only out through a runtime exception that they are not (or through experience). I just plead not to condemn parameterless queries (assuming one knows what one is doing, of course).

Comment: @Christoph That contradicts your earlier comment then :) I take that to mean beginners should always use parameters and only old hands use strings lol

Comment: @Christoph Sorry, but that's just wrong. Easier debugging is not true when you have to go through convoluted hoops to escape the string. Honestly Dale is right, there are far, far more questions on [so] with bad/no escaping as compared to difficulties with parameters, like 50:1 and that's not an exaggeration. Forced Parameterization is really not the answer, it has other unintended side-effects, I'm a DBA and would not switch it on unless I had no other choice. Parameters enable re-use of query plans, and if someone can't get their head round `varchar` lengths then they shouldn't be doing ....

Comment: @Christoph .... databases. No-one calls `Prepare()` on `SqlCommand`, there is no need and it usually makes things worse, you won't find anyone here recommending it. Re `int`, you may find [this article from Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/) interesting, although it is a bit tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @Charlieface: We do. We always call `Prepare()` on the command because we experienced incorrect behavior when we didn't. But that's exactly what I mean: You used it all the years and had no problems, and we can only use it with Prepare() reliably => parametrized queries may introduce new issues. And of course you need to know about SQL injection if you decide against it and of course you need to know about the performance impact (although it is usually negligible).

Comment: @Christoph I'd love a demonstration of an issue you are having (I assume you are referring to SQL Server only?) that `Prepare()` solves. It usually makes things worse because it prevents parameter sniffing, which is *usually* beneficial. I'm a DBA, and let me tell you the worst performing queries are often the non-parameterized ones recompiling again and again. I've had few-1000 row inserts into a table variable from embedded literals take a server to its knees. Let's not mention the clearing of the query plan cache within a few hours. The performance impact is absolutely not negligible.

Comment: @Charlieface: In my experience it is often beneficial that query execution plans are freshly compiled each time and no stale plans (that may be correct or outdated) are used.

Comment: @Christoph That is completely ridiculous. [The engine determines when a plan needs recompiling, one of the many reasons it will do so is **a change to statistics**.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#recompiling-execution-plans). [And having multiple plans compiled again and again for the same query is a waste of resources.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/why-multiple-plans-for-one-query-are-bad/) The plan cache is there for a reason: compilation, especially on complex queries, is a huge CPU hog

Comment: @Everybody: I surrender! Use parametrized queries!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you parameterize your SQL to avoid things like SQL injection:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblCars SET rentID=@rentId WHERE carID=@carId;", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rentId", Convert.ToInt32(rentID));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carId", Convert.ToInt32(carId));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Can I nest these "using" with another using?

Comment: YESSS THAT WORKED! OMG I WAS WORKING FOR HOURS ON THAT THING!!! THANKS A LOTT!!

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: ^^^^ seriously, what Smor said **do not** use [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: What I could use instead in tough "real life" applications? Should I use something like array?

Comment: @Stayheuh what do you mean by tough real life situations?

Comment: I don't know how to say, like real life applications, serious bussiness apps?

Comment: I know what a real life app is, I don't know what you mean by "something like an array" - just use parameters correctly (i.e. not AddWithValue) for you real business app.

Comment: @DaleK I must say, I do use `AddWithValue` on `int`,`bool` and `Guid` because it saves on typing and I know it works correctly. Definitely wouldn't touch it for `string`, `byte[]` or table types

Comment: @Charlieface yeah well you know what you are doing and what to look for if something goes wrong. But for a single rule of thumb, I would say don't.